# How to display QR code image in React from string type

Tags: html, reactjs, string, png, qr-code

I have the **string type** of **QR code**, like this:

> "data:image/png;base64,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"

I am not sure how to display the **QR code** in React from this **string type**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an img tag like the below:

```
let img =
  'data:image/png;base64,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';

<img src={img}/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if the Qr_code will change every time you can use like this:

```
 <img    src={`data:image/png;base64,${qr_code}`}/>
```

the qr_code is the value that changes every time so you can every time generate a new QRcode

Comment: How to get back the octet stream string in a variable ? Doing a `console.log(data)` on the  `finally` clause of the `fetch` displays in console an empty Array (size : 0).
Is it because the response's payload is an octet stream and not JSON ?
How to solve it ? Thanks a lot.